# Dynamically resized images, relative/absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css

I'm having some serious difficulties getting my image height to resize relative to the browser window -- the width resizes fine, but the height stays the same. I've tried height: 100% and height: auto, as well as height: 100vh, but no dice. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the way my divs are laid out, here is the relevant css:

```css
.main {
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0%;
    height: auto;
    left: 0%;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

.container {
    overflow: auto;
    }

.alphaleft {
    background-color: #fff;
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    float: left;
    }

.alpharight {
    background-color: #fff;
    right: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    float: right;
    }

.alphaleftimg{
    background: url("images/bg.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    left: 0%;
    top: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 6;
    }

.alpharightimg{
    background: url("images/bg2.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    left: 0%;
    top: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 6;
    }

.floaters {
    clear: both;
    }
```

and here is my html in a jsFiddle to save post length: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PPryq)

I basically want the page to look like this:
[image]

with the image height also scaling with the browser window.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 adds a background-size property that allows you to specify that you want the background to cover its container:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

If you're looking for a solution that is backward compatible, consider not using background-image to specify the image, but use an actual  tag, and then set the dimensions on it to 100%.

Comment: Yeah I have background-size on each of my images :( the issue is that I need my height of my container to automatically adjust to the size of the image